# Evaluate an expression while debugging a dump file in WinDBG or Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, windbg, dump

I know that the answer is probably no, but since I am slightly desperate, I ask in case there is some trick I don't know.

I need to call a function while debugging a dump file, but apparently this is impossible either using windbg or visual studio on windows.

any hope for me?

Comment: Not sure. Can you add Any barebones scenerio  simple how to do x when iam on y type to try is it user mode function kmode etc

Comment: Which function do you want to call and where do you want to call it? What do you expect to happen? As it stands, it's very unclear what you want to do, what you have tried and what's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle to see how this is possible.

A dump file, in it's basic form, is a collection of data, not an executable environment. If you try to call a function using, say, `.call` in WinDbg, whilst looking at a dump file, you will likely get this message:

> No runnable debuggees error......

or something like that.

In order for you to call a function, the program's code must be loaded into a memory address that can be executed against. In other words, you must open/attach a debugger to the running process (.exe, etc) you wish to interact with.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought, I was hoping the debugger could have loaded the code from the dmp file or something like that.